# Event listener not working in a loop

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm running into an issue with the `addEventListener()` function. I'm trying to build a menu based on variables from an array (I won't bother explaining why it's setup this way).

Here is the code:

```
var _Dirt = document.getElementById("dirt");

_Dirt.addEventListener('mouseover', function () { menuOver(true, this, _dirtY); }, false);
_Dirt.addEventListener('mouseout', function () { menuOver(false, this, _dirtY); }, true);

var _DirtDiv = _Dirt.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

for (nLink in Men["dirt"]) {

    var _lnk = document.createElement('p');
    _lnk.className = 'menu';
    _lnk.innerHTML = Men["dirt"][nLink][0];
    _lnk.addEventListener('click', menuLoop(Men["dirt"][nLink][1]), false);

    _DirtDiv.appendChild(_lnk);
    _DirtDiv.innerHTML+= '<br />';

}
```

Here is the menuLoop function (in case you are concerned that I'm not correctly binding the variable right:

```
function menuLoop (n) {

    return function () {

        menuLink (n);

    }

}
```

Now, the annoying part is that the event listener is working fine on the `_Dirt` element, but not at all on the `_lnk` element. Even when I change it to to `_lnk.onclick = function () { //something }`, it won't work (as a matter of fact, the `onclick` attribute won't even show up in the DOM).

I have another loop function that also attaches an event listener to an element, and that one works perfectly fine...and the code is very similar. What adds to the frustration is that this code used to work flawlessly. I actually don't even recall making any changes to this code at all. I tried to isolate this function in the code to see if there were any breakpoints in my script, but it the issue remains.

Please let me know if you require any other parts of my code.

Comment: have you tried just passing a hard coded `function(){alert('boom!');}` instead of `menuLoop(Men["dirt"][nLink][1])` for the event handler just to be sure the event fires?

Comment: *"the `onclick` attribute won't even show up"* That's because you're not adding an attribute. You're working directly with the DOM and its event system.

Comment: @Yaniro: Yes, I have tried that. No avail. am not i am: I was referring to when I add an onclick event. I know that when adding an event listener it won't show up in the DOM.

Comment: Try changing the second parameter of addEventListener for __lnk_ elements to `function () { menuLoop(Men["dirt"][nLink][1]); }` just the way you did for __Dirt_ element.

Comment: @Coder: No avail. I think Felix Kling is right and this is an issue with DOM assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This is under the assumption your data structures are all correct)*

Your problem is

```
_DirtDiv.innerHTML += '<br />';
```

This basically takes the child nodes of `_DirtDiv`, serializes them to a string (HTML), concatenates `'<br />'` and assigns it back to `innerHTML`. The browser will parse the string and create the corresponding DOM nodes.

The identity of the DOM node you created before is lost and so is the event handler. This process destroys and creates **new** DOM nodes which are different than the one you created before.

If you want to add a `br` node, use DOM manipulation as well:

```
_DirtDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

---

Example from the Chrome console which demonstrates that the nodes are different:

```
> var node = document.createElement('div');
  undefined
> node.id = 'foo'; 
  "foo"
> document.body.appendChild(node);
  <div id=​"foo">​</div>​
> node === document.getElementById('foo');
  true                                       // nodes are the same
> document.body.innerHTML += '<br />';
  "... long HTML string ..."
> node === document.getElementById('foo');
  false                                      // nodes are different
```

Comment: +1 Excellent catch.  If a line break is desired, it should be added via DOM insertion rather than innerHTML modification.

Comment: That was a code formatting issue. The `<br />` in the question was being interpreted as HTML in the SO page.

Comment: Ah, I see... Didn't notice the context of the `innerHTML` use. He's destroying the old DOM. +1 Another example of why one should not do `elem.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: @Felix Kling: That was it! I don't know why it worked before though, but I don't really care now I suppose. Thanks a bunch!